# labelling with subscript and superscript a line in a plot using result values in R plot

Tags: r

I worked out some results and obtained a value (VALUE) with asymmetric errors (UERROR, and LERROR).
I would like to have a label for a R plot using these values. 
With symmetrical errors, I an easily get the expression for the label as follows
`label<-paste(VALUE,"±",ERRORS)`
For the asymmetric errors, I am not sure how to proceed to have have the +error as a superscript and the - error as a subscript. 
I have tried 
`label<-paste(VALUE[LERROR]^UERROR)` but I get a label with "NA".
I would like to be complete to add a "+" and a "-" in front of the appropriate errors and complete the expression with the units "kg".
I am really a total novice at R but am sure this is possible having seen simultaneous subscripts and superscripts built with R but manually entered values. K^2[t] etc.
Really intrigued as how to proceed. 
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3):

Use `bquote`:

```
value <- 1
upr <- 1.2
lwr <- 0.5

plot.new()
text(0.5, 0.5, bquote(.(value)[.(lwr)]^.(upr)), cex = 10)
```

[image: resulting plot]

However, I wouldn't understand this notation without further explanation.

See also `help("plotmath")` for further advice regarding mathematical annotations in plots.

Comment: I wanted to create a label with the value as shown but with a "+" in front the superscript and a "-" in front of the subscript which woulld repalce the ± habitually used for errors when they are symmetrical.

Comment: OK, feel free to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am not sure how to add the "+" sign and "-" sign and the "kg" after to the text. I also would appreciate it if you could tell me how you feel I should rather present the asymmetrical errors as the aim is to be as clear as possible. Thank you!